# Gradle skip JaCoCo during test

Tags: gradle, jacoco

I have an issue in which test task is failing intermittently (I doubt it is, because Jacoco is triggering [generating reports] during test).

Is there a way to disable running of jacoco during test?

I can create a new task solely for generating coverage reports (I would like to know how that can be done too). There are many cases in which I don't really need a test coverage report while running test task.

Comment: Can we see a stacktrace ? you can run your gradle cmd with --stacktrace, to answer your question - yes, you can exclude a task from execution phase with -x taksname

Comment: Please find it at http://pastebin.com/UtWMYtwk

I want to exclude the jacoco tasks that run along with test,  I dont know the names of these tasks.

Comment: it might be that is not test task is failing? Does this runs on Jenkins by any chance or local ?

Comment: it is running on Jenkins, and no tests are failing on jenkins

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit

---

**After reading the second answer and testing it myself I greatly suggest and appreciate the below blog post as it's true the instrumentation still happens even after disabling or removing the tasks**.

https://poetengineer.postach.io/post/how-to-conditionally-enable-disable-jacoco-in-gradle-build

---

If it does runs on Jenkins, error 137 might be out of memory issue.

If it runs on Jenkins please try to extend the memory and check this link.

[I'm getting OutOfMemoryError](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/I'm+getting+OutOfMemoryError)

Jacoco tasks:

```
jacocoTestReport    -   JacocoReport    Generates code coverage report for the test task.
jacocoTestCoverageVerification  -   JacocoCoverageVerification  Verifies code coverage metrics based on specified rules for the test task.
```

To find out which tasks have which dependencies you can do

```
gradle tasks --all
```

To exclude the task with cmd you can

```
gradle test -x taskToExclude
```

Programmatically you can use a task graph to exclude it

```
gradle.taskGraph.useFilter { task -> yourstuff}
```

or simply remove it from test task dependencies

```
test.dependsOn.remove("jacocoTestReport")
test.dependsOn.remove("jacocoTestCoverageVerification")
```

Additional resource worth checking:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html

Comment: Thank you, I head that jacoco consumes a lot of memory when it executes. 

I will try tweaking the JVM settings, but if possible, I would like to avoid the jacoco execution during test task. 

I would like to add a new target solely for generating reports, when required.

Comment: @Suraj I have edited the answer i hope it solves your problem :)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Krystian_K . I will try this and will let you know.

Comment: thanks for providing this great answer & references to full article

Answer (score 10):

I found that if you do the apply plugin then the jacoco instrumentation takes place even if you have done the dependsOn.remove as noted in the accepted answer.  You can tell the instrumentation is still occurring as a file called build/jacoco/test.exec is created even if the jacoco reports themselves are not created.

I had to extract the jacoco plugin apply to a separate .gradle file and conditionally include it like:

```
if (jacocoEnabled.toBoolean() )  {
  project.logger.lifecycle('applying jacoco build file')
  apply from: "jacoco.gradle"
}
```

Then my jacoco.gradle file looks like:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'


test {
  jacoco {
    append = false
    destinationFile = file("$buildDir/jacoco/test.exec")
  }
}

  jacocoTestReport {
      reports {
          xml.enabled true
          xml.destination file("${buildDir}${jacocoXMLDestination}")
      }
  }

  test.finalizedBy jacocoTestReport
```

This took my build time from 4 minutes to 3 minutes - providing some savings.

Comment: This is great. In the ext section of my root build.gradle, I added the following "extra" variable, so that I can enable jacoco via a gradle command-line option (-PjacocoEnabled=true): `jacocoEnabled = System.properties.getProperty("jacocoEnabled") ?: "false"`

Also, I'm pretty sure you have to kill your gradle daemon to get it to unload the jacoco plugin if it was already loaded.

Comment: It turns out that the plugin is not responsible for instrumentation of class files. Because a Java agent cannot be used with Android, Jacoco's offline instrumentation must be used, and this is triggered by setting testCoverageEnabled to true. If you set `testCoverageEnabled jacocoEnabled.toBoolean()`, this will prevent instrumentation.

Comment: I have a blog post in which I wrap all of this into a more complete explanation: https://poetengineer.postach.io/post/how-to-conditionally-enable-disable-jacoco-in-gradle-build